# Outputting Query to Textfile

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code (which thanks to the users of stackoverflow I got the markup I needed :) ). However, I have come to a road that I have no knowledge of what so ever. I need to output this formatted table of the query to a text file on the server.

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
 mysql_connect("hostname.net", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 

// Get all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cards ORDER BY card_id") 
or die(mysql_error());  

echo "";
echo " Name AgeTitlebar ";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo ""; 
    echo $row['card_id'];
    echo ""; 
    echo $row['title'];
    echo ""; 
    echo $row['item_bar'];
    echo ""; 
} 

echo "";
?>
```

I know I could use something similar to

```
<?php
$myFile = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Bobby Bopper\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

but I am sure that it cant be the best solution. So I guess my question is does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you sure this is not the best solution - PHP writes the file what more do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nicest solution, particularly if you are short on memory, would be to put the writing into the loop:

```
$fh = fopen('cards.csv', 'w');

// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    fputcsv($fh, array($row['card_id'], $row['title'], $row['item_bar']), "\t");
} 

fclose('cards.csv');
```

Note that I have used [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to output the data in CSV format (using a tab  as the delimiter).  This should be easy to read by hand, and will also be easily understood by, for instance, a spreadsheet program.  If you preferred a custom format, you should use [`fwrite`](http://php.net/fwrite) as in your question.

Comment: I did try this, but it does keep telling me that title_bar and everything is undefined. hmm

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

especially:

```
[INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
// Make sure the file exists, do some checks.
// Loop trough result set and append anything to the file.
while (false !== ($aRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($rResult))) {
    $sCreateString = $aRow['field1'].';'.$aRow['field2'];
    file_put_contents('example.txt', $sCreateString, FILE_APPEND);
}
// Done
```

If you need an exact dump of the database table, there are better options. (much better actually).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a text file, then there's nothing wrong with what you've suggested.

There's lots of information in the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

It depends entirely on how you want to store the data inside the file. You can create your own flat-file database format if you wish, and extract the data using PHP once you've read in the file.